# Scrolling through UIButtons on a UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 50 UIButtons.
Only 10 UIButtons are allowed to show on the UIView at a time.

How do I set this up to allow the user to scroll through the list of 50 buttons?

thx

Comment: Put the 50 buttons into a scrollview, add the scrollview to the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other users have said you can do it with a scroll view.

Personally I think it might be easier with a tableview, (provided its not a specific 10, just 10 consecutive buttons). You could arrange the tableview to remove the separators, and adjust the cell heights so only 10 cells fit on the screen.

This seems simpler to me. And you may have no need for UIButtons if you implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I need specific graphics, and also rounded corners on edges.  If this can be done in the tableview, Please let me know... thank you

Comment: Add a subview to the tablview cell, using your design. Or if you've already done the buttons, just add them as a subview to the cell. a code normally. that way all the scrolling is done for you quickly.

Answer (score 0):

add the 50 buttons to a scroll view.

Set the scroll view to be paging enabled..

be the delegate and check the content offset of the scroll view to determine which page user is on..

load the buttons of the page..and remove other page buttons to free up memory.(add later when user come back to page)